# AWS CodePipeline with ECS Blue/Green deployment fails with internal error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I have a CodePipeline set up where changes to code builds and pushes an image to ECR. I am looking to automate updating ECS with the new image as it is built. I have configured the ECS Blue/Green action but when it runs it fails almost immediately with a message about an "Internal Error". There is no failed deployment created in CodeDeploy.

I have configured CodePipeline with two inputs:

1. the source code used to build the image
2. a zip in S3 containing the appspec.yaml and the taskdef.json

When either input changes I rebuild the container and push to ECR tagged 'latest'. The next step should be a Blue/Green deployment to ECS. I have configured CodeDeploy and the job works if triggered manually.

When it is triggered via CodePipeline it will fail and I receive a message "Action execution failed
InternalError. Error reference code: <some id>". I suspect that there may be some underlying issue with IAM but I can't find where to start looking at this stage. There is no failed deployment shown in CodeDeploy so I don't see a way to get more information about what has failed.

My policy for CodePipeline is copied from the one documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/how-to-custom-role.html#view-default-service-role-policy

I have read through the troubleshooting docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html

I believe my issue is similar to the one described here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=897822

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit more reading of similar posts here, on serverfault.com and the AWS forums I have been able to resolve this.

In my case the issue was that my taskdef.json was not valid. It took me several hours going through each step to realise that while it was valid JSON it only included the container definitions section. On fixing that it appears to now be working correctly.

In the end I have two, related, CodePipelines. One for deploying updated ECR images to ECS (described above) and the other which updates infrastructure and generates a zip containing `taskdef.json` and `appspec.yaml`. If that zip changes then my container pipeline runs; likewise if the container image source changes. It needs more testing but right now this appears to be working very smoothly.

Comment: "On fixing that it appears to now be working correctly." .. Can you please elaborate, I appreciate you've answered your own question, but a more detailed answer would help. TIA

Comment: @OneMoreNerd Unfortunately, I don't really remember, I solved it and moved on. I said that I'd only included the container definitions section but I'm not sure exactly what else was needed. Looking at source changes around this time I see that I ended up filling out basically the whole file (see the bottom of this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-task-definition.html). I think, ultimately, I just had a basic misunderstanding of what was required and had left out a lot of stuff that was needed. I wonder if AWS has improved the error messages at all since.