# AWS CodePipeline with ECS Blue/Green deployment fails with internal error | take 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, blue-green-deployment

Firstly, I am aware that there is a similar question ([AWS CodePipeline with ECS Blue/Green deployment fails with internal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55897126/aws-codepipeline-with-ecs-blue-green-deployment-fails-with-internal-error)), however the person that answered it, didn't provide sufficient detail.

As per this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/1388058/getting-internal-error-in-aws-code-pipeline-while-deploying-to-ecs .. I have gone through the aws guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#constraints... To ensure that all the "required" fields are in my **taskdef.json** (*below*)

As for my *pipeline* (build) **buildSpec** ...

```
    - printf '{"ImageURI":"%s"}' $ECR_REPO_URI:demo > imageDetail.json
          - echo Build completed on `date`

  artifacts:
    files:
      - imageDetail.json
```

The *pipeline* **build stage** setup is simple, I simply set BuildArtifact as the output. So I can ref the imageDetail.json from the *pipeline* **deploy stage**.

As for my *pipeline* (deploy) **AppSpec** ...

```
version: 0.0

Resources:
  - TargetService:
      Type: AWS::ECS::Service
      Properties:
        TaskDefinition: <TASK_DEFINITION>
        LoadBalancerInfo:
          ContainerName: "pipeline_demo"
          ContainerPort: 80
        PlatformVersion: "LATEST"
```

The *pipeline* **deploy stage** setup is as follows:
Input artifacts: BuildArtifact, SourceArtifact; then:

- Amazon ECS Task Definition: SourceArtifact "taskdef.json"
- AWS CodeDeploy AppSpec file: SourceArtifact "taskdef.json"

Dynamically update task definition image: BuildArtifact

- Placeholder text in the task definition: IMAGE1_NAME

(..some of which was sourced from this guide: https://medium.com/@shashank070/in-my-previous-blog-i-have-explained-how-to-do-initial-checks-like-code-review-code-build-cddcc21afd9f

.. and the taskdef:

```
{
  "family": "devops-platform-ecs-task-def",
  "type": "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition",
  "properties": {
    "containerDefinitions": [
      {
        "name": "pipeline_demo",
        "image": "<IMAGE1_NAME>",
        "cpu": "1024",
        "memory": "1024",
        "essential": true,
        "portMappings": [
          {
            "hostPort": 0,
            "protocol": "tcp",
            "containerPort": 80
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "ExecutionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/devops_codepipeline",

    "NetworkMode": "null",
    "PlacementConstraints": [
        "type": "memberOf",
        "expression": ""
    ],
    "ProxyConfiguration": {
      "type": "APPMESH",
      "containerName": "",
      "properties": [
          {
              "name": "",
              "value": ""
          }
      ]
    },
    "RequiresCompatibilities": [
      "EC2"
    ],
    "Tags": [
      {
        "key": "",
        "value": ""
      }
    ],
    "TaskRoleArn": "",
    "Volumes": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": ""
            },
            "dockerVolumeConfiguration": {
                "scope": "task",
                "autoprovision": true,
                "driver": "",
                "driverOpts": {
                    "KeyName": ""
                },
                "labels": {
                    "KeyName": ""
                }
            }
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Nonetheless, I still get the error ...
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found that the inclusion of another policy **AWSCodeDeployRoleForECS** solved the issue. It referenced in the aws guide for CLI (we've been administering via the console thus far, hence I spotted this by chance alone) [Create a Service Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-service-role.html) (CLI). After including the policy, the pipeline has progressed past the issue listed issue, but has encountered another "Invalid Configuration Action; Container list cannot be empty." - which your answer may solve? Nonetheless, at least I have a more meaningful error to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Your task definition is not valid. From a quick look I can see following invalid property:

```
"type": "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition",
```

Please review the sample Task defs here [1]. Also I would recommend to remove any extraneous section from taskdef so they do not interfere in any way.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/example_task_definitions.html

Comment: Hi @shariqmaws, I actually found that the inclusion of another policy AWSCodeDeployRoleForECS solved the issue. It referenced in the aws guide for CLI (we've been administering via the console thus far, hence I spotted this by chance alone) Create a Service Role (CLI). After including the policy, the pipeline has progressed past the issue listed issue, but has encountered another "Invalid Configuration Action; Container list cannot be empty." - which your answer may solve? Nonetheless, at least I have a more meaningful error to work with. 1 vote up for the effort, thanks!